# TextRank with Scattertext Visualisation

Tags: nlp, visualization, spacy, textrank, pytextrank

I recently tried to visualize TextRank using code, but I realized that the terms in the graph are not lemmatized. Is there a way to fix the following code so that all words in textrank_df['parse'] are lemmatized? I checked the pipeline components and all required components are in place ('tok2vec', 'tagger', 'parser', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer', 'ner'), so I'm really not sure where went wrong.

```
import pytextrank
import spacy
import scattertext as st
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe("textrank", last=True)
   
convention_df = textrank_df.assign(
    parse=lambda textrank_df: textrank_df['Combined'].apply(nlp),
)

corpus = st.CorpusFromParsedDocuments(
    convention_df,
    category_col='Response Variable',
    parsed_col='parse',
    feats_from_spacy_doc=st.PyTextRankPhrases()).build()
```

I tried the following code1, but it shows:
AttributeError: module 'pytextrank' has no attribute 'TextRank'.
I think it might be something to do with the format after this alteration.

- code 1

  convention_df = textrank_df.assign(
  parse=lambda textrank_df: textrank_df['Combined'].apply(lambda x: [token.lemma_ for token in nlp(x)]))

I also tried code 2 which adds use_lemmas=True in PyTextRankPhrases() but did not work as well. The word is still presented in its original form.

- code 2

  corpus = st.CorpusFromParsedDocuments(
  convention_df,
  category_col='Response Variable',
  parsed_col='parse',
  feats_from_spacy_doc=st.PyTextRankPhrases(use_lemmas=True)).build()

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't have a `scattertext` tag yet, although this would be helpful to add since there are already 18 questions about that (awesome) library. I don't have enough reputation to create tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the authors of `PyTextRank` and I've tried out the code shown above.

There are some issues with the usage of `scattertext` in that example. I don't think the line

```py
convention_df = textrank_df.assign(
    parse=lambda textrank_df: textrank_df['Combined'].apply(nlp),
)
```

would work correctly. There's no source text defined, from what I can see, and also the `textrank_df` variable is considered by Python as an undefined value.

Is this code based on the example in `scattertext` ?https://github.com/JasonKessler/scattertext/blob/master/demo_pytextrank.py

My suggestion would be:

1. Start with a text source which can be used in a simple `spaCy` pipeline.
2. Get the `PyTextRank` pipeline for `spaCy` configured and running the way you want it to work.
3. Then integrate into the declarative pipeline in `scattertext` and debug that portion.

Might also be good to ask Jason & co. from `scattertext` for what they'd recommend.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the incorrect code!
For your question, textrank_df is my own dataset that I am working on. It is correct that the code I showed follows the link that you mentioned, I just changed some parts of it to the variable in my dataset.